# Reading h5py files into tensors

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, h5py

So I have a training set and a test set both in h5py format. I also have a data_load function that loads the files and returns NumPy arrays. The main problem is I don't need NumPy as I am working with Tensors. I am expecting to have an x&y tensor of size N(batch size) and D_in(input size for each image) and D_out(Output size of each tensor).

The problem:

x&y do not get converted to tensors of dimensions mentioned below.If anything their types remain to be numpy.ndarray. Any help is appreciated.

```
def load_data(train_file, test_file):
# Load the training data

train_dataset =h5py.File(train_file, 'r')


# Separate features(x) and labels(y) for training set
train_set_x_orig =np.array(train_dataset["train_set_x"][:])
train_set_y_orig =np.array(train_dataset["train_set_y"][:])

# Load the test data
test_dataset =h5py.File(test_file,'r') 

# Separate features(x) and labels(y) for training set
test_set_x_orig =np.array(test_dataset["test_set_x"][:]) 
test_set_y_orig =np.array(test_dataset["test_set_y"][:])

classes = np.array(test_dataset["list_classes"][:]) # the list of classes

train_set_y_orig = torch.from_numpy(train_set_y_orig.reshape((1, train_set_y_orig.shape[0])))
test_set_y_orig = torch.from_numpy(test_set_y_orig.reshape((1, test_set_y_orig.shape[0])))

return train_set_x_orig, train_set_y_orig, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y_orig, classes






x = torch.Tensor(N, D_in)
y = torch.Tensor(N, D_out)
train_file="data/train_catvnoncat.h5"
test_file="data/test_catvnoncat.h5"
x,y,_,_,_=load_data(train_file,test_file)
```

Comment: This doesn't affect your conversion of `y` to tensor, but `test_dataset["test_set_x"][:]` returns an array.  There's no need for the `np.array(...)` wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not convert `train_set_x_orig` to a torch tensor before returning.
Either use `torch.from_numpy()` on `train_set_x_orig` before returning as you do with `train_set_y_orig` or cast it to a tensor before assigning to `x`.

However, `y` should be of type `torch.tensor`.

---

Below is a demonstration that explains the issue:

```
# some sample tensor
In [27]: x = torch.Tensor(3, 2)    

# check its type
In [28]: type(x)   
Out[28]: torch.Tensor

# some sample ndarray
In [29]: arrx = np.arange(6).reshape(3, -1)   

# assign array to tensor
# note that now the object `x` refers to the numpy array object
In [30]: x = arrx     

# see that the type() of `x` is now numpy ndarray
In [31]: type(x)  
Out[31]: numpy.ndarray
```

---

Also, as hpaulj pointed out in the comments, there is no need to wrap the sliced objects from h5py in `np.array()` since the sliced objects are already of type numpy ndarrays. So, you can just get rid of them and the code will look more cleaner!